# How to display table of top 5 URL with their status and percentage on splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Need a table to show the top 5 URL as given below in Splunk. Is this possible in Splunk? I tried many ways but I can't get all status of a URL as a single row.

```
API                         200        204  400 401 499 500

/wodetails/ACP              895(50%)    -    -   -   -   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the [chart](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.0/SearchReference/Chart) command can be used:

```
index="main"  source="access.log" sourcetype="access_combined"
| chart c(status) by uri, status
```

| uri | 200 | 204 | 400 | 499 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /basic/status | 11 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| /search/results | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

To add the percentages, you can use [eventstats](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.0/SearchReference/Eventstats)

```
index="main"  source="access.log" sourcetype="access_combined"

| eventstats count as "totalCount" by uri
| eventstats count as "codecount" by uri, status
| eval percent=round((codecount/totalCount)*100)

| eval cell=codecount." (".percent."%)"

| chart values(cell) by uri,status
```

| uri | 200 | 204 | 400 | 499 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /basic/status | 11 (79%) | 1 (7%) | 1 (7%) | 1 (7%) |
| /search/results | 3 (100%) |  |  |  |